# Stokes Theorem - Line integral.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Im trying to use Stokes Theorem to solve the following integral:
$$\int_C(x^{2}z)dx+ (3x)dy+ (-y^3)dz$$ where $C$ is the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, oriented counter clockwise.

This is my attempt thus far:
$\textbf{F} = \langle x^2z,\:3x,\: -y^3\rangle$

$\text{Curl}\: \textbf{F} = \nabla \times \textbf{F} = $$
\begin{vmatrix} \mathrm i&\mathrm j&\mathrm k\\ \partial_x&\partial_y&\partial_z\\ x^2z&3x&-y^3 \end{vmatrix}
=\langle -3y^2, x^2, 3 \rangle. $

Now, what is my d$\textbf{S} = \textbf{n}\:d\textbf{S}$? My surface is just the unit circle on the xy-plane (z=0) with radius 1 right? Since it's oriented counter clockwise, then $\textbf{n}$ is just <0,0,1>. 
Then,
$$(\nabla \times \textbf{F}) \cdot  \textbf{n}\:d\textbf{S} = \langle-3y^2, x^2,3\rangle\cdot \langle 0,0,1 \rangle = 3$$

$$
=\iint_D 3 \:dA
$$

Since $dA$ is just the area of the circle with radius 1 , then we have $3\pi(1)^2 = 3\pi$.

Is this logic sound? The correct solution is $3\pi$ but I am not sure if my steps to get the answer is right. Any feedback / clarification will be nice. Thank you!

Comment: You may may choose any surface $S$ such that the boundary of $S$, that being $\partial S$, is the unit circle in the $xy$ plane. Your choice of unit disk (circle and inside) in the $xy$ plane as $S$ was a good choice, as it simplified the problem. Your work is correct.

Comment: I also think your logic and answer are correct - but I think you have an (irrelevant) error in the $j$ component of $\mathop{\rm curl}  F$.

Comment: Ah yes, u're right Peter. Thanks guys!

Comment: fyi - I copied your correction of the curl into the equation below it with the dot product... OK?